# Repository with two branches diverged from remote, how to fix?

Tags: git, git-rebase

This is the current state of my repository:

[image]

What I want to do is get rid of that dangling commit (which is currently HEAD locally), and make `origin/master` look like the last commit and finally get rid of the `tmp` branch entirely.

I think I should start by merging `origin/master` with local `master` and then rebasing `tmp` into `master`, but I'm not sure.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both in one rebase command:

```
git checkout master
git rebase tmp
```

That will replay your dangling commits on top of tmp (and origin/master, which is a direct ancestor of tmp)

Then you will have to force push (`git push --force`)